# Howto turn an empty row return value of a function into an empty table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a function that returns a string or NULL. In order to get an empty table instead of an empty row I did the following:

```
SELECT destination
FROM (
  SELECT dynamicAlias(
    'teststring'
  ) AS destination
) AS d2
WHERE destination IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 1
```

Is there a better way? I can change *dynamicAlias()* to return an empty string if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
SELECT dynamicAlias(
    'teststring'
  ) AS destination
HAVING destination IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 1
```